# Using LINQ to select the smallest, most common number in an array

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an unsorted array, which has multiple pairs of identical numbers, how can I find the smallest of the most common number?

```
int[] arr = new int[] {8, 6, 5, 2, 5, 9, 6, 9, 2, 3}; // unsorted array
// Array.Sort(arr); // I could sort the array

int mostCommon =  arr.GroupBy(ii => ii)  //Grouping same items
            .OrderByDescending(abc => abc.Count()) //now getting frequency of a value
            .Select(bcd => bcd.Key) //selecting key of the group
            .FirstOrDefault();   //Finally, taking the most frequent value
```

In the above case, I want to get 2, but the query returns 6. If I sort the array before running the query, I will get 2, but I want to find out if there is a way to use LINQ to get the smallest most common value from an unsorted array.
I am not interested in very fast execution of the code.

Comment: Side note: you may want to add remark to the post that you need just *correct* code, and don't care about theoretical performance as so far answers provide just that (obviously you'd look for O(n) solution instead of O(n log n) if you need performance)

Comment: You're right, mjwills, my code is incorrect. I initially tried with ThenBy, but I didn't know how to build the query. Could you show the correct code for the largest most common number?

Comment: Thanks. It's quite easy for those who can think ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two 2's, two 6's and two 9's - assuming that you mean the lowest (2) should have precedence in the event of a tie, then you simply need to add in a second ordering, like so:

```
int mostCommon = arr.GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()) // First precedence = frequency
            .ThenBy(grp => grp.Key) // Second precedence is lowest number first
            .Select(bcd => bcd.Key)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit, re O(N) solution**

Here's one way, resorting to imperative means, which can be done in a single pass through the data. Given that you've specified single digits in your array, I've assumed a range of 0-10 for a bin counting array (with the benefit that the values are initialized to zero), but obviously adjust if your range is larger. If your values are large and likely to be sparse, then you may need substitute a Dictionary for the array.

```
var bins = new int[10]; // Adjust this to size / use Dictionary if sparse
var hiCount = 0;
var smallestMostCommon = int.MaxValue;
foreach(var a in arr)
{
   var newCount = ++bins[a];
   if (newCount > hiCount) // 1st Precedence : Frequency
   {
      hiCount = newCount;
      smallestMostCommon = a;
   }
   else if (newCount == hiCount && a < smallestMostCommon) // 2nd : Lowest preferred
   {
      smallestMostCommon = a;
   }
}
```

Further optimizations are possible, I'm sure, notably that at any point in the loop, that if the number of elements remaining is less than the difference between the first and second highest bins, that the loop can terminate early.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: That's funny that we just had long discussion on Meta (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361065/special-case-questions-duplicates-of-more-general-ones/361068#361068) how `OrderBy` is wrong theoretical solution for "single most common..." and how OP should not accept such solution and demand better one with linear time... (In my opinion sorting as shown here is fine for most cases except where performance is critical, but than LINQ will likely not be used anyway :) )

Comment: Alexei, please provide a faster solution and I will accept your answer instead. In my case, I was happy with a solution that works, but in the interest of everybody else who will come across this question, it is better to accept the most performant solution.

Comment: @Nick_F - I've given O(N) a stab

Comment: Thank you very much, Stuart.

Answer (score 3):

You need to order items again before `Select`, so `FirstOrDefault` would return the smallest group key:

```
int smallestMostCommon =  arr.GroupBy(ii => ii)  //Grouping same items
        .OrderByDescending(abc => abc.Count()) //now getting frequency of a value
        .ThenBy(g => g.Key) // Make sure we get the smallest key first
        .Select(bcd => bcd.Key) //selecting key of the group
        .FirstOrDefault();   //Finally, taking the most frequent value
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a sorting algorithm to sort the values in the array in numerical order. Search 'Bubble Sort'. I like to loop this algorithm to ensure accuracy. Then perform the same sort on the product to determine like values, and print the result.